# CDF of the difference of two Gaussian mixtures

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have two Gaussian mixtures, $X_D$ and $X_{\overline{D}}$:

$$
f(X_D) = \sum_{c=1}^m f(X_D\mid C=c)P(C=c) = \sum_{c=1}^m \phi(x-\mu-g(c))P(C=c),
$$

$$
f(X_\overline{D}) = \sum_{c=1}^m f(X_\overline{D}\mid C=c)P(C=c) = \sum_{c=1}^m \phi(x-g(c))P(C=c),
$$

for some function $g(c)$; that is, $X_D$ and $X_{\overline{D}}$ are conditionally normally distributed with variance 1 and means $\mu + g(c)$ and $g(c)$, respectively. Furthermore, conditional on $C$, $X_D$ and $X_\overline{D}$ are independent.

I would like to derive the CDF of $X_D - X_{\overline{D}}$. Specifically, I would like to know

$$P(X_D - X_{\overline{D}} > 0).$$

It seems like this would be straightforward with conditional densities and standard convolution formulas, but I keep ending up with answers not supported by simulations.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: One should not use the same symbol to refer both to a random variable and to the argument to its density function, nor use identical symbols to refer to several different density functions.  If $x\mapsto f_X(x)$ (a function of (lower-case) $x$) is the density function for the random variable (capital) $X$, then we know that $f_X(3)$ is not the same as $f_Y(3)$, and distinguishing in the same way between capital and lower-case letters makes it possible to understand things like $\Pr(X\le x) = \Phi(x)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: To sum up, $X_D=\mu+g(C)+Y$ and $X_{\bar D}=g(C)+\bar Y$ where $(Y,\bar Y)$ is i.i.d. standard normal (and independent of $C$), thus $X_D-X_{\bar D}=\mu+Y-\bar Y$ is normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\var}{\operatorname{var}}$The conditional distribution of $X_D-X_{\overline D}$ given the event $C=c$ is normal with expected value $\Big(\mu+g(c)\Big) - g(c) = \mu$ and variance $1+1=2$, since
\begin{align}
\var(X_D - X_{\overline D} \mid C=c) & = \var(X_D \mid C=c) + \var( -X_{\overline D} \mid C=c) \\[10pt]
& = \var(X_D \mid C=c) + (-1)^2\var( X_{\overline D} \mid C=c).
\end{align}

Since the conditional distribution of $X_D -X_{\overline D}$ given $C=c$ is thus seen not to depend on $C$, the marginal (or "unconditional") distribution must be the same as that, i.e. it is normally distributed with expectation $\mu$ and variance $2$.

Then we have
$$
\Pr(X_D - X_{\overline X} >0) = \Pr\left( \frac{(X_D-X_{\overline X}) - \mu}{\sqrt 2} > \frac {0 - \mu} {\sqrt 2} \right) = 1-\Phi\left( \frac{-\mu}{\sqrt 2} \right)= \Phi\left( \frac{\mu}{\sqrt 2} \right).
$$